# Redirecting from one method to another in a same controller in Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: redirect, spring-mvc

I have a user controller. It has three methods for listing users, showing a user add page and saving a user. When the user is saved, it should redirect to the user listing page.

In my case when I try to do the redirect, I am getting the following error.

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myApp/cases/cases] in DispatcherServlet
```

Below is my entire UserController.

```
@Controller

@RequestMapping("/users")

public class UserController extends BaseController {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(userController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list() {
        logger.info(" [list] - showing user list.");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("userList");
        mav.addObject("users", new ArrayList<User>());
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView form() {
        logger.info(" [form] - showing new user creation form.");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("userForm");
        mav.addObject("user", new User());
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(User user) {
        logger.info(" [save] - saving user.");

        return "redirect:/users";
    }
}
```

Am I doing the redirection proper way?

Comment: I thought this was a simple issue and someone will surely have the solution for this. But to my disappointment no answer till now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the context of DispatrcherServlet. For example, if URL pattern of dispatcher servlet (in web.xml) is 'myApp' then it should be: `return "redirect:/myApp/users";`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I add /myApp and later on If I had to change the app name then I will have to make changes in the application. As well /myApp will be different in production environment.

Comment: @Ashish, you can make it configurable and store in a properties file. For example, you can pass it in method of Controller as `@Value("#{myProperties['my.servlet.path']}") String servletPath`.

Comment: But I have seen many examples on line where they dont specify the app name while redirecting.

Comment: @Ashish, it is not true. servlet prefix is required. Note that the context root (usually the war file name) is different from URL pattern of the DispatcherServlet. Please see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix